# Relink another Dropbox account on server

Tags: dropbox, vps, centos6

I have Dropbox setup on my Centos 6 VPS that syncs my site. This allows me to work all within Dropbox and not have to deal with FTP programs or the command line. However, I mistakenly synced an account that syncs ALL my folders which takes up more space. I created another Dropbox account to only have one particular folder that I want to sync to my server. How can I switch those accounts?

Note: I'm horrible at the command line.

I'll add a bounty of 50pts (in 2 days) if anyone can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the exact tutorial I followed before:

> NOTE: If you want to change the account it is linked to, unlink it from the first account, then kill the running dropbox process, start it up again (with “~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &”) and obtain the new host_id with dbreadconfig.py . If you don’t restart the dropbox client, it will give the same host_id (which for some reason cause me to be unable to change the account it is linked to).